# EF Core 2.0 Enums stored as string

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I was able to store an enum as a string in the database.

```
builder.Entity<Company>(eb =>
{
    eb.Property(b => b.Stage).HasColumnType("varchar(20)");
});
```

But when it comes time to query EF doesn't know to parse the string into an enum. How can I query like so:

```
context
    .Company
        .Where(x => x.Stage == stage)
```

This is the exception: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Opportunity' to data type int

Comment: Have you tried `context
    .Company
        .Where(x => nameof(x.Stage) == stage)`

Comment: It's not the query that's the problem I don't think. It's the hydration of the model.

Comment: How did you populated database then. Because EF should not allow you to build the model.

Comment: Why not? I used Database.Migrate and some seed data. It's in the database fine.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Value Conversions feature is new in EF Core 2.1.

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading
>   from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value
>   to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from
>   a value of one type to a value of another type (for example,
>   converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

```
public class Rider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EquineBeast Mount { get; set; }
}

public enum EquineBeast
{
    Donkey,
    Mule,
    Horse,
    Unicorn
}
```

You can use own conversion

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.Mount)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (EquineBeast)Enum.Parse(typeof(EquineBeast), v));
}
```

or Built-in converter

```
var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<EquineBeast>();

modelBuilder
    .Entity<Rider>()
    .Property(e => e.Mount)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I can accept this answer as my question was specific to 2.0

Comment: I think mostly people use the latest 2.x version of ef core. To make it accurate I'd update the question accordingly and then select this answer.

Comment: If it solves the issue and your requirement is not really tied the specified version, I agree with @BluE, it is a good and helpful answer :)

Comment: This can be implemented slightly more straightforward with attributes, simply by marking the corresponding column as `nvarchar`.
[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#pre-defined-conversions)

Comment: @szydzik, Is it possible to search by this column from c# code?

Comment: @szydzik, Scaffolding will overwrite the dbcontext file. How did you handle that?

Comment: Shorthand for `.HasConversion<EnumToStringConverter<EquineBeast>>()`

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this in ef6?

Answer (score 15):

You can use this to convert all the Enum of all the properties of all the entities into a string and vice versa :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserContext> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // Configure your model here
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder model)
        {
            foreach (var entityType in model.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (property.ClrType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                    {
                        var type = typeof(EnumToStringConverter<>).MakeGenericType(property.ClrType);
                        var converter = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new ConverterMappingHints()) as ValueConverter;

                        property.SetValueConverter(converter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of checking `property.ClrType.BaseType == typeof(Enum)` we can use the convenient property `property.ClrType.IsEnum`

Comment: Note that this code won't work on nullable enum properties. To support those, add an `else if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.ClrType)?.IsEnum == true)` with the same code, except pass `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.ClrType)!` to `MakeGenericType()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this much more easily with a one-liner attribute.

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(24)")]
public EquineBeast Mount { get; set; }
```

That's all you need to do!  This is a string to enum value conversion by explicitly specifying the database column type as an attribute on the property.  *([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#pre-defined-conversions))*

I had gotten the same error as the OP because I was originally using the `[MaxLength]` attribute instead.

*(The original question is for EF 2.0, and this feature starts in EF 2.1 as others mention in their answers.  But google lead me here so I decided to add a useful answer.)*