# How to Compare Enum to additional string value

Tags: c#

I have values being returned as strings from a database that have names that make them unsuitable for enum names, e.g. "Color.Red". How do I name my enums something else but then equate them to these string values when it comes to writing conditional logic?

```
public enum ItemColor
{
      Red,
      Green,
      Yellow    
}

var dbList = new List(){"Color.Red", "Color.Green", "Color.Yellow"}


if (dbList.Contains(ItemColor.Red)))
{
   //do something
}
```

Is there some way that I can easily decorate the enum with an additional string value equal to what I am returning from the database?

Comment: `var newList = dbList.Select(Enum.Parse<ItemColor>).ToList();` maybe? Then you have it as the enums rather than strings.

Comment: How are you fetching data from the DB?  If you're using EF Core, it has [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721246/ef-core-2-0-enums-stored-as-string) to specify a converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing build-in. You can always write your own method with custom attribute. Something to get you started:

```cs
static class CustomEnumNameGetter
{
    // "cache" reflection here
    private class Internal<T> where T: struct, Enum
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<T, string> Dictionary;

        static Internal()
        {
            var customPrefixAttribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<CustomPrefixAttribute>();
            var prefix = customPrefixAttribute?.Name ?? string.Empty;
            Dictionary = Enum.GetValues<T>()
                .ToDictionary(v => v, v => prefix + Enum.GetName(v));
        }
    }

    public static string GetName<T>(T value) where T: struct, Enum => Internal<T>.Dictionary.TryGetValue(value, out var name)
        ? name
        : string.Empty;
}

class CustomPrefixAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public CustomPrefixAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
[CustomPrefix("Color.")]
public enum ItemColor
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Yellow    
}

if (dbList.Contains(CustomEnumNameGetter.GetName(ItemColor.Green)))
{
    //do something
}
```

Or just concatenate prefix in-place (i.e. `if (dbList.Contains($"Color.{ItemColor.Red}"))`).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
if (dbList.Contains("Color." + ItemColor.Red))
```

The expression `"Color." + ItemColor.Red` evaluates to `"Color.Red"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following conversion method:

```
private static string ToString(ItemColor itemColor)
{
    return "Color." + itemColor;
}
```

To use:

```
if (dbList.Contains(ToString(ItemColor.Red)))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use Split to find Part of Enum list(Green,Yellow)

Then you can get enum(with Enum.TryParse)

finally, compare between Enum(ItemColor ) and enum list(myItemColor)

```
var dbList = new List<string>() { "Color.Green", "Color.Yellow" };


if (dbList.Any(d => Enum.TryParse(d.Split('.')[1], out ItemColor myItemColor) && myItemColor==ItemColor.Red) )
{
    
}
```